# boost::python::list got value segment error

Tags: c++, boost-python

I wrote a piece of test code of `boost::python::list` but I got `segment fault`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void test(const boost::python::list & action, int i);

void test(const boost::python::list & action, int i) {
    cout << "step into here" << endl;
    double a = boost::python::extract<double>(action[i]);
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    boost::python::list action;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) action.append(1.0);
//    int n = boost::python::extract<double>(action.attr("__len__")());
//    cout << n << endl;
    test(action, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that segment fault occurred at

```
double a = boost::python::extract<double>(action[i]);
```

But the list has a length of 10 and I want to get the value with index 0. How can I fix it?

Comment: Missing `Py_Initialize();`...

Comment: @DanMašek Do I need call `Py_Initialize()` every time when a `boost::python::list` is initialised?

Comment: No, you just call it once at the beginning of your program. This is a case of embedding the Python interpreter in an executable -- you need to initialize the interpreter before you use it. | I haven't studied the implementation of Boost.Python to be able to explain why the constructor and `append` work fine, while the `operator[]` need the interpreter to be initialized, but I've tried it, and it solves the problem. | If you read the [tutorial about embedding](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html) you'll see a mention of this function call.

Comment: @DanMašek I read the content of the link you provided, my question is I want to created a shared library for Python to use and In the C++ code, I will use `boost::python::list` and `boost::python::extract` in a function, should I call `Py_Initialize()` in that function?

Comment: If the shared library in question is intended to be `import`ed by Python code running in an interpreter, then you don't need `Py_Initialize()` (the interpreter is already initialized and running at that point).